# Assign roles to other users drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, user-roles

I am creating three user types in Drupal 7.

1. company
2. publisher
3. administrator

(Default drupal 7.)

Company has permission to create article and view own article (ONLY). Publisher has permission to create, delete, view, edit, and publish unpublished article (Only). By default all articles can be viewed by all guest users.

What type of configuration is required in Drupal 7?

Comment: If guest users (anonymous users) can see everything, restricting permissions for the company role doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default core user permissions can do this. You have only to set the Article content type unpublished by default (I suppose you mean for company "create article and view own UNPUBLISHED article").

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).